# Bind Error is not Shown in Spring Form validation

Tags: jsp, validation, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I am using `<spring:Bind>` tag For form validation. But It is not showing any error. I searched lot of solutions for this problem but I cant get any correct solution. Please help.

Here the sample code

**Dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.studentadmissioncontroller" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
 <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/studentmessages" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

    @Size(min=2,max=30)
    private String studentName;

    private String studentHobby;

// corresponding getter and setter

}
```

**Phone.java**

```
public class Phone {
    private Integer phoneNumber;

    //getter and setter
}
```

**StudentController.java**

```
@Controller
public class StudentAdmissionController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
        model.addObject("student1",new Student());
        model.addObject("phone",new Phone());
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/submitAdmissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student1") Student student1, @ModelAttribute("phone") Phone phone, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
            return model1;
        }
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
        return model;
    }

}
```

**AdmissionForm.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Student Registration</h1>
    <form action="/FirstSpringMVCProject/submitAdmissionForm.html"
        method="post">

        <form:errors path="student1.studentName" />
        <spring:bind path="student1.studentName">
            <input type="text" name="${status.expression}"
                value="${status.value}">
            <br />
            <c:if test="${status.error}">
                Error codes:
                <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var="error">
                    <c:out value="${error}" />
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
        </spring:bind>
        <spring:bind path="student1.studentHobby">
            <input type="text" name="${status.expression}"
                value="${status.value}">
            <br />
            <c:if test="${status.error}">
                Error codes:
                <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var="error">
                    <c:out value="${error}" />
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="phone.phoneNumber">
            <input type="text" name="${status.expression}"
                value="${status.value}">
            <br />
        </spring:bind>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit this form by clicking here" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**AdmissionSucess.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h3>Congratulations!! Registered Sucessfully</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Student Name :</td>
            <td>${student1.studentName}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student Hobby :</td>
            <td>${student1.studentHobby}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone :</td>
            <td>${phone.phoneNumber}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to solve the problem to display error message if there any error during form validation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have a `BindingResult` following each model attribute. Also why are you having 2 model attributes as that is basically only complicating things. Also you are destroying the model yourself by returning a new and empty `ModelAndView` you should at least do `new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm", result.getModel());` else you get nothing in your model.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Can you please explain me with an example? and thanks for quick reply...